# Why does my salesforce access token expire after a certain time?

Tags: rest-api, security-token, refresh-token

I am running into an issue with one of our apps and am new to salesforce. We have an azure function that takes data and inserts into salesforce using the Salesforce Rest API. This usually works great. The problem is that after a certain amount of time all inserts/updates fail with the message

```
“Session expired or invalid, ERRORCODE: INVALID_SESSION_ID”
```

I believe this is because our function grabs the salesforce security token at Azure Function startup and does not refresh it unless it gets restarted. I have the code tested and ready to refresh the token, but am unsure of how to do this with an app that is always on like Azure Functions.

On the other hand, I'm not sure on this 100% and am wondering if this error could happen from another source, like too many sessions enabled.

How do these access/refresh tokens work & what do I have to do to refresh them/fix the expiration on them? Am I going to have to constantly check the token after a certain period of time and update it manually, or is there a way to do that in my initial request?

The initial grant uses a username/password and looks like this.

```
var sfAuthRequest = new SfAuthRequest
            {
                ClientId = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SalesforceApiIntegrationConsumerKey"),
                ClientSecret = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SalesforceApiIntegrationConsumerSecret"),
                UserName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SalesforceApiIntegrationLoginId"),
                Password = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SalesforceApiIntegrationUserPassword"),
                GrantType = "password",
            };
```

After setting those fields we make a request to get the token and give us access to Salesforce.

```
var authRequest = CreateAuthRequest();
                var authResponse = new SfAuthResponse() { AccessToken = _currentAccessToken };

                var restAuthRequest = new RestRequest
                {
                    Method = Method.POST,
                    RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
                };

                restAuthRequest.AddQueryParameter("grant_type", authRequest.GrantType, false);
                restAuthRequest.AddQueryParameter("client_id", authRequest.ClientId, false);
                restAuthRequest.AddQueryParameter("client_secret", authRequest.ClientSecret, false);
                restAuthRequest.AddQueryParameter("username", authRequest.UserName, false);
                restAuthRequest.AddQueryParameter("password", authRequest.Password, true);
                authResponse = await ExecuteAsync<SfAuthResponse>(restAuthRequest);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Salesforce Access Tokens/Session IDs expire only during periods of inactivity. The window is automatically refreshed for a token if it is used at least 50% of the way through its expiration. For example, if a token has a 2 hour life, and you make an API call at 59 minutes, it will expire in 1 hour, 1 minute. However, if you make an API call at 1 hour exactly, it's now good for another two hours. However, if you attempt to log in more than five times per user per Connected App, you'll kick off the oldest session. Make sure you're not using too many sessions at once.

Generally speaking, you should not need to worry about sessions just "disappearing" randomly, so long as you don't try to log in excessively. That said, your code should be willing to accept an INVALID_SESSION error at any time and be prepared to log in again. Just organize your logic so that you don't flood yourself with a bunch of logins at once to avoid the problem of disappearing sessions.

You may consider increasing the session timeout period, which may help. For example, you can set that user to have a 24-hour session expiration, allowing a large period of time where you'll hit the "automatic refresh" window of 12 hours. You can set this by profile, instead of for all users, in order to keep other sessions on shorter timeouts.

Comment: Awesome @sfdcfox , thanks for the clarification! I found a place in salesforce in my connected app called 'Session Policies'. The timeout value was set to None, but I changed it to 24 hours. Does this now mean that our sessions will wait for 24 hours until they expire as mentioned? Does it also matter that our initial session request is from a Singleton? If we consistently hit the api in a 24 hour period will we need to refresh the tokens at all?

Comment: @user1299379 Yes, sessions will last 24 hours, and refresh as long as they're used every 12 hours. You can share a token across multiple calls (e.g. Singleton), but don't go overboard; there are concurrent cursor limits. A few concurrent sessions are fine, though.

Comment: Thanks for all the support! I'll give it a shot with the session timeout update and keep it as a singleton for now. I expect us to get a lot of calls with this so the refresh shouldn't be a big deal.