# Maintain session permanently for user signed in through Connected App / Oauth

Tags: connected-apps, oauth

I am setting up a Salesforce Rest endpoint for a 3rd party to send data to. I've created a specific user who has API only login access. My goal is to generate an access token that will not expire. I would prefer to provide the 3rd party who will be sending data to this REST Endpoint just the access token rather than the username and login of the integration user

Is this possible? I've successfully generated an access token through Postman and have successfully POST(ed) data to the REST endpoint in Salesforce. But the access token seems to expire overnight, returning this error when i try to send data to the REST endpoint after ~10 hours

```
   {
        "message": "Session expired or invalid",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_SESSION_ID"
    }
```

Once i generate a new access token with the standard Oauth post call, i can again send data utilizing the new access token to the REST Endpoint without issue

[image: SF Oauth flow]

So is there a way to generate an access token that will not expire (unless i decide to revoke it)?

Comment: There isn't, but what you can do is get the refresh token and use that to silently get a new, valid access token. See the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5).

Comment: Ok makes sense, how do you get the refresh token initially in the services/oauth2/token POST call? I've tried adding a scope parameter to the body but get the error back "scope parameter not supported"

Comment: Take a look at sfdcfox's answer and the documentation that Salesforce provides. You should find it all in the same area (look at the doc navigator sidebar to the left of the documentation itself).

Comment: The documentation you and he linked starts off with the assumption of possessing the Refresh Token. I had found this "The OAuth 2.0 user-agent and the OAuth 2.0 web server flows can request refresh tokens if the refresh_token or offline_access scope is included in the request." But putting scope=full%20refresh_token only result in the error "The value of the "scope" parameter contains a character that is not allowed or the value exceeds the maximum allowed length". Thank you for the help though, i'll start a new question

Comment: Rather than using an encoded space as %20 have you tried "+"? Alternatively it may be that postman wants to do the encoding for you and you should just use space directly...?

Answer (score 2):

No, but yes.

Access tokens are tied to a session for the target user in the target org, and are subject to the org's session timeout policies (which have a maximum value of 24 hours before timeout).

...but since it *is just a session*, the [same timeout refreshing behavior of "normal" sessions applies](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/335791/24889). I.e. make a request using the token any time in the last 50% of the timeout window and the timeout is reset.

For a 1-hour timeout starting at noon, if you make a request at 12:35, the token is now valid until 13:35 (instead of timing out at 13:00).

Frequent enough requests can keep an access token valid practically indefinitely.

Comment: It isn't really practical to keep an access token alive in this way; it's too hit-and-miss and a refresh token approach should be used instead (this is, after all, exactly what this is for).

Comment: @PhilW It's plenty practical... for server-server data flows that make regular requests (or can schedule a heartbeat/keepalive request) at a frequency of at least 1/2 the timeout. For better or worse, that's what has kept the outside of Salesforce (and thus outside of my control) component of a Salesforce integration running smoothly for 4 years (the auth part at least. The data itself is still hot garbage).

Comment: Fair comment. I had in mind other OAuth 2 scenarios, such as mobile app to server, where this isn't practical.

Comment: I still think ensuring you are set up for refresh tokens is the best approach.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using the [Refresh Token Flow](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=5). Refresh tokens can't be used as access tokens, but can have an indefinitely long shelf life, months or even years, if configured to do so. The flow inside your app then looks like the following pseudocode:

```
result = doApiCall();
if(result.status == 403) { // forbidden if expired
  newSession = refreshSession(); // try to get new access token
  if(newSession.status != 200) {
    reportSessionError(); // request user login again
    return; // don't try to handle the result
  } else {
    result = doApiCall(); // This time should work
  }
}
handleResult(result);
```

In addition, if it's an API only user, you could also create a Permission Set to extend session durations to 24 hours and assign that Permission Set to the user. This will result in overnight tokens not expiring as long as they're used between 12 and 24 hours after being created or last used.